# Rabbitmq , send message to appropriate consumer

Tags: java, android, rabbitmq

I have three applications,

1. java rest api
2. android application
3. rabbitmq service

When android application is turn on it listens some queue  then application can make `http request` and java `rest api service` put some message to this queue.

The question is, how to send message from `rest api service` to only one user, because all users are listening the same queue?

Comment: why don't you make each app (user) create it's own queue ?

Comment: for example all users will listen the same queue , if i need to send message to this queue all users wil get it

Comment: yes i understand , and that's why i told you to create a queue for each user, queue_user_10, queue_user_12, queue_user_4310 ... etc and each user will listen to it;s queue

Comment: Thank you, sorry for misunderstanding , but is it a good idea, maybe there are some methods to send message from one queue to appropriate user?

Comment: sending the message is something u can control (which queue, which exchange ...) but distributing the message to workers is something in the hands of MQ server, u can't control it, if u are trying to do some chat system, i am not sure if MQ as-is is a good choice, unless you make a queue for each user, because Message for MQ is not the same as a Message to a chat system